# What is the difference between calling `done()` and calling `return` after a function completes execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am confused on whether I should call `done()` after a function completes execution or `return`. I understand that calling done will mean that I have to pass it as a parameter to the function. What instances will one opt for calling `return` rather than `done()`?

i.e.

```
var foo = 2;
it('returns 2 on completion', function(done) {
    expect(foo).toEqual(2);
    done();
});
```

or

```
var foo = 2;
it('returns 2 on completion', function() {
    expect(foo).toEqual(2);
    return;
})
```

Comment: Use `done` for asynchronous tests to indicate that it finished. `return` in the second case make no difference and can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you use a `done()` callback or simply return depends on the API you're using. A `done()` callback is necessary in a variety of asynchronous contexts. Off the top of my head:

- Tests, like your example
- [Express middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) (they call it `next()` instead of `done()`)
- [Methods in the async library](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) (they call it `callback()` instead of `done()`)

In all of those contexts, the `done()` callback is necessary because they need to do work that can't all finish before the `return`. For example, tests might include random timeouts, Express middleware might make network requests, etc.

Important note: *every* function returns. The `done()` callback is a convention you use on top of that when `return` isn't enough because it happens too soon.